# CURL a LAMBDA REST-API after enabling AWS-IAM authorization

Tags: curl, aws-lambda

Let,s say, i have authorized "iam"-User in my region to access a resource path in my API.

My question is right now:

How can i test after enabling iam-authorization on my API using CURL  ?

One of my resource path looks like following:

```
https://my-api-id.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/music/{id}
```

Comment: Use your `AccessKey` and `SecretKey` in Authorization Headers

Comment: @HarshitRastogi please could you provide a sample CURL request to this, also tell what is supposed to be the **AccessKey** and the **SecretKey** for an AWS-IAM-User (maybe in your answer)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly get control access to API gateway using your IAM user permissions by attaching the required policies. [More info here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/)

Then get your credentials for that IAM user by clicking on `My Security Credentials` from the dropdown menu located upper right.

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://my-api-id.execute-api.AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/dev/music/{id}' \
  -H 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY/20210902/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=b28388012a84499650cf766bed595b51a8de988da0874140af78bd1775b95bb9' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'X-Amz-Date: 20210902T055703Z'
```

This will be your CURL request but you have to create the signature string first [see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html)

Comment: I will let you know!

Comment: i think the best way is to send the request in a code e.g. Python as mentioned here **https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html**

Comment: Please you have to **checkout or verify the edit queue of your answer**, as there are edits **available**, since e.g. region is `Credential` header is not okay! Then i will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think the best way is to send the request in a code e.g. Python as mentioned [here in official documentation examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html).

For example, if your credentials have been set locally, then this example could be use for a GET request to your REST API:

```py
# Copyright 2010-2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
#
# This file is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
# You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the
# License is located at
#
# http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/
#
# This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
# OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
# language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
#
# ABOUT THIS PYTHON SAMPLE: This sample is part of the AWS General Reference 
# Signing AWS API Requests top available at
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html
#

# AWS Version 4 signing example

# IAM API (CreateUser)

# See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html
# This version makes a GET request and passes request parameters
# and authorization information in the query string
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac, urllib
import requests # pip install requests

# ************* REQUEST VALUES *************
method = 'GET'
service = 'iam'
host = 'iam.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'https://iam.amazonaws.com'

# Key derivation functions. See:
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python
def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

# Read AWS access key from env. variables or configuration file. Best practice is NOT
# to embed credentials in code.
access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print('No access key is available.')
    sys.exit()

# Create a date for headers and the credential string
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amz_date = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ') # Format date as YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope


# ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

# Because almost all information is being passed in the query string,
# the order of these steps is slightly different than examples that
# use an authorization header.

# Step 1: Define the verb (GET, POST, etc.)--already done.

# Step 2: Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query 
# string (use '/' if no path)
canonical_uri = '/' 

# Step 3: Create the canonical headers and signed headers. Header names
# must be trimmed and lowercase, and sorted in code point order from
# low to high. Note trailing \n in canonical_headers.
# signed_headers is the list of headers that are being included
# as part of the signing process. For requests that use query strings,
# only "host" is included in the signed headers.
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n'
signed_headers = 'host'

# Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use, either SHA-1 or
# SHA-256 (recommended)
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

# Step 4: Create the canonical query string. In this example, request
# parameters are in the query string. Query string values must
# be URL-encoded (space=%20). The parameters must be sorted by name.
# use urllib.parse.quote_plus() if using Python 3
canonical_querystring = 'Action=CreateUser&UserName=NewUser&Version=2010-05-08'
canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + urllib.quote_plus(access_key + '/' + credential_scope)
canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Date=' + amz_date
canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Expires=30'
canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers

# Step 5: Create payload hash. For GET requests, the payload is an
# empty string ("").
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(('').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# Step 6: Combine elements to create canonical request
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash


# ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amz_date + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
# Create the signing key
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)

# Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


# ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************
# The auth information can be either in a query string
# value or in a header named Authorization. This code shows how to put
# everything into a query string.
canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Signature=' + signature


# ************* SEND THE REQUEST *************
# The 'host' header is added automatically by the Python 'request' lib. But it
# must exist as a header in the request.
request_url = endpoint + "?" + canonical_querystring

print('\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Request URL = ' + request_url)
r = requests.get(request_url)

print('\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```